# Exponential circuits

Tags: circuit-design, multisim

**Is there any way to generate the following exponential outputs in oscilloscope of multisim?**

[image: graphs]

Comment: The I/V curve of a diode has an exponential shape.

Comment: i want it on oscilloscope. with 'x' and ' t '

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: I have seen a similar question to this before ....cant find it now ...

Comment: @MituRaj YES STILL CANT FIND THIS TOO

Comment: @Wheatley I HAVE A CIRCUIT WHEREBY I NEED TO ATTACH AN EXPONENTIAL FUNCTION i.e EXP(X) AND EXP(Y) BUT THE QUESTION IS THAT HOW AM I GOING TO DO THIS?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with an arbitrary waveform generator. Also, many low cost function generators from China available on Ebay include this waveform among their menu of waveforms.

Comment: I NEED IT TO SIMULATE IT ON MULTISIM ...

Comment: I need it to simulate on multisim on the oscilloscope